# Navigation Drawer Activity

Tags: android, navigation

I am building an Android Application with Navigation Drawer. On Clicking the items in the ListView, I want to startActivity say, Help. But the Navigation Drawer is Lost on navigating to that contentView. Any Ideas how to? I know that's simple and silly. Still I would heavily count on your help. Thanks in advance.

Content of Help.class

```
public class Help extends Activity {    

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.help);
    }

}
```

Contents of help.xml file:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Help Section"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
```

:D

Comment: create a `BaseActivity` that has navigation drawer then `public class Help extends BaseActivity`

Comment: Ok try this tutorial on navigation drawer. Check this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

Comment: Thanks @Raghunandan But frankly I am a beginner. Can you be more specific with some code? Thank you again

Comment: can you please be little specific??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link for better understanding on navigationdrawer
[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8hSIP2ha-g)

Once you have your navigation drawer done put a listview in the drawer layout and put setOnclickListener to those.
Use Intents to specify them where to go.

Hope it helps